# Change time value in div tags with the same class(javascript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an Index View in an MVC 5 project. This view uses a partial view, the partial view is included in the index like this:

```
<div id="le">
    @Html.Action("_ls", "Home")
</div>
```

After that, the Index will be populated with the code from partial view _ls.
I want to change the inner HTML of the divs with class="mtime". This div has a time value with the format HH:MM in UTC. I want to make it show user's local time. So, I added this javascript code before the end of the body tag in in the partial(nOT in Index as I had initially)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('.mtime').each(function (obj) {

                var date = obj.InnerHTML;
                var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);

                var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
                var hours = date.getHours();

                newDate.setHours(hours - offset);
                obj.InnerHTML = newDate;

            });


        </script>
```

but the value in the divs never changes

Comment: Are you wanting this to trigger every so often because this will only be executed once.

Comment: yes, so I ll probably want to ad it in the partial view front end code

Comment: What does `var date = obj.InnerHTML;` output?

Comment: it does not change anything... the time remains the same

Comment: @StephenMuecke That will output `undefined`. He means obj.innerHTML

Comment: It's `innerHTML` and not `InnerHTML`

Comment: @mattytommo, Not only that, even it it returned something, its not going to be a javascript `Date` object

Comment: @StephenMuecke Good shout

Comment: `$.each()` call the function with the index as first argument not the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do that using the constructor of a date and the `UTC` suffix :

```
$('.mtime').each(function() {
    var time = $(this).text();

    var date = new Date();

    date = new Date(date.toDateString() + ' ' + time + ' UTC');
    $(this).text(date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes());
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oac38p31/)

Comment: I will try it as soon I ll be back at home!

Comment: It Wooorks!! great!!but there is one small issue, some zeros are not displayed, check this image: http://i90.photobucket.com/albums/k270/vengaspeed/timec_zpstfqazzei.jpg

Comment: I found out how to fix it! it is simple, I will just add if clauses and add the zeros if needed...Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is the error in your code, it's `innerHTML` **not** `InnerHTML`.

The second is that you're trying to parse a JavaScript date from the objects innerHTML, that won't be a `Date` object.

Secondly, you need to tell your code to run in set intervals by using `setInterval`, which we can do by wrapping your code in a `function` and then calling it every `n` seconds (I've used 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        //First, let's call it for page load
        calculateTimes();

       //Now, let's call it every 1 second:
       setInterval(calculateTimes, 1000);

        function calculateTimes() {
            $('.mtime').each(function (obj) {
                var date = obj.innerHTML != ""
                    ? new Date(obj.innerHTML)
                    : new Date();
                var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);

                var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
                var hours = date.getHours();

                newDate.setHours(hours - offset);
                obj.innerHTML = newDate;
            });
        }


    </script>
```

Comment: I put the javascript code in partial view now, so calculateTimes() not needed?

Comment: @MVCnewbie It's needed if you want to call every so many seconds yes

Comment: unfortunately it does not work...I ll better do the time change with C# and razor...Thank you for your effort